# What causes System.BadImageFormatException when constructing System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection

Tags: .net, sqlite, 32bit-64bit, system.data.sqlite

I've broken the code down to the smallest possible statement:

```
Dim cn As System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection
```

And I get the following error when calling the code from a WinForm applicaiton:

> System.BadImageFormatException: Could
>   not load file or assembly
>   'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.65.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or
>   one of its dependencies. An attempt
>   was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format. File name:
>   'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.65.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139'

Yet calling the same piece of code from MS Unit Test I do not get the error, plus the full code set works as expected.

Comment: See similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370344/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-a?lq=1

Answer (score 62, accepted):

SQLite contains unmanaged code, you can't run it on a 64-bit operating system unless you deploy the 64-bit version.  Quick fix: Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform Target = x86.

Comment: If only I'd asked the question two hours ago :-) This would suggest to me that MS Test runs in 32 bit. Correct?

Comment: Yes, running corflags.exe on mstest.exe shows that it was also forced to run in 32-bit mode.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you use correct assembly with respect to 32 and 64 bits.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by downloading a new version of the SQLite DLL via NuGet:
http://gurustop.net/blog/2011/05/19/sqlite-database-nuget-package-common-problems-solved/