# How to set a project output platform to x86 in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, configurationmanager

In my solution with several projects I am trying to change the `Platform` from Any CPU to x86.  But x86 is not in the drop down.  What do I need to do to be able to choose x86?

I need to change to x86 because of an `System.BadImageFormatException` error, as per this question: [What causes System.BadImageFormatException when constructing System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048914/what-causes-system-badimageformatexception-when-constructing-system-data-sqlite-s)

[image]

And, in a possibly related problem, the newest project in the solution is missing one of the configurations from the configuration drop down:

[image]

It should have a "Staging" configuration like all of the other projects, but does not.  How do I add it?

**EDIT:**

If I choose the "New ..." option, then it asks me to copy from "Any CPU".  If I copy from "Any CPU", isnt that just the same as using "Any CPU" in the first place?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Both the *Configuration* and *Platform* drop downs have a:

- `<New...>`

option.  In fact you **have them circled** in your annotated screenshots!

Use that option to create the "Staging" configuration and the "x86" platform for the corresponding project.

Comment: Yeah I saw that but was not sure if it was the right option.  x86 is not a new platform so why would I have to chose "new ..." to create an option for it?  Same thing for the "Staging" configuration, it isn't new it already exists.

Comment: @JK: Those are **solution** configurations and platforms, not **project** configurations and platforms.  They are different.  It is **new** to the project that doesn't have it yet.

Comment: If I choose the "New ..." option, then it asks me to copy from "Any CPU".  If I copy from "Any CPU", isnt that just the same as using "Any CPU" in the first place? See new screenshot in the question.  And should I click the "Create new solution platforms" checkbox or not (I guess not)

Comment: @JK: Copying copies the **other** settings that don't depend on the platform; it will still create an **x86** specific setting even when you copy from **Any CPU**.  As far as creating solution configurations, it doesn't matter if the configurations already exist.  If they didn't exist, you might or might not want to create them.

Answer (score 1):

You can set project platform using the `/platform` compiler switch like below

```
/platform:string
```

Where the `string` can be either of `x86, Itanium, x64, or anycpu (default)`

```
csc /platform:x86 myprogram.cs
```

In case you want to achieve the same from Visual Studio then you can follow the below steps

> 1. Open the Properties page for the project.
> 2. Click the Build property page.
>
> 3.Modify the Platform target property.

See [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zekwfyz4(v=vs.80).aspx) For more information on the same.

Answer (score 1):

I removed a solution platform and created it again with **Create new project platforms** check-box. It helped.