# c# visual studio sql lite

Tags: c#, sql, load

my friend and I are currently a program in which we are using a sql lite database. When he is compiling the project, the database loads up without any problems. But when I try to compile the project (which works fine) and load the database the following error appears:

> System.BadImageFormatException was unhandled
>     HResult=-2147024885
>     Message=Die Datei oder Assembly "System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.66.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Es wurde versucht, eine Datei mit einem falschen Format zu laden.
>     Source=PrisonArchitectSavegameEditor
>     FileName=System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.66.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139
>     FusionLog==== Zustandsinformationen vor Bindung ===
>   LOG: Benutzer = TIETZE\tietze111
>   LOG: DisplayName = System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.66.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139
>    (Fully-specified)
>   LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/Dropbox/C#/WIP/PrisonArchitectSavegameEditor/PrisonArchitectSavegameEditor/bin/Release/
>   LOG: Ursprünglicher PrivatePath = NULL

## Aufruf von Assembly : PrisonArchitectSavegameEditor, Version=2.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

> LOG: Diese Bindung startet im default-Load-Kontext.
>   LOG: Die Anwendungskonfigurationsdatei wird verwendet: D:\Dropbox\C#\WIP\PrisonArchitectSavegameEditor\PrisonArchitectSavegameEditor\bin\Release\PrisonArchitectSavegameEditor.vshost.exe.Config
>   LOG: Die Hostkonfigurationsdatei wird verwendet: 
>   LOG: Die Computerkonfigurationsdatei von C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config wird verwendet.
>   LOG: Verweis nach der Richtlinie: System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.66.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139
>   LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///D:/Dropbox/C#/WIP/PrisonArchitectSavegameEditor/PrisonArchitectSavegameEditor/bin/Release/System.Data.SQLite.DLL.
>   ERR: Das Setup der Assembly konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden (hr = 0x8007000b). Die Suche wurde beendet.

StackTrace:

> ```
>   bei PrisonArchitectSavegameEditor.Form1.LoadDatabase()
>    bei PrisonArchitectSavegameEditor.Form1.tabControlSaveGameActions_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Dropbox\C#\WIP\PrisonArchitectSavegameEditor\PrisonArchitectSavegameEditor\Form1.cs:Zeile 652.
>    bei System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
>    bei System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.WmSelChange()
>    bei System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>    bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>    bei System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
>    bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>    bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmNotify(Message& m)
>    bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>    bei System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
>    bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>    bei System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
>    bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
>    bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>    bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>    bei System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>    bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>    bei System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>    bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>    bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>    bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>    bei PrisonArchitectSavegameEditor.Program.Main() in d:\Dropbox\C#\WIP\PrisonArchitectSavegameEditor\PrisonArchitectSavegameEditor\Program.cs:Zeile 20.
>    bei System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>    bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>    bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>    bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>    bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>    bei System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
> ```

InnerException:

The error also appears when I start the exe which he compiled.
Also the error appears to come up when calling the function and not in the function itself:
[image: Error]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What causes System.BadImageFormatException when constructing System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048914/what-causes-system-badimageformatexception-when-constructing-system-data-sqlite)

Comment: Are you both 32-bit, both 64-bit, or different ?

Comment: @Alvin - I reckon you have it

Comment: @HughJones No, just a Google search. But actually I think I've read about `System.Data.SQLite` doesn't support x64 before.

Comment: we have both x64, so that can't be the problem

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to install the provider for SQLLite:

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Comment: Ok, we don't know what the problem is. Installing didn't help. We will try mysql now, online it's cooler anyway. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try change Visual Studio **Processor Architecture**