# System.Data.SQLite.DLL no longer loads after switching target framework

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-4.0, reference, .net-4.5

I had to switch from .net 4.5 to .net 4.0 because some of my customers still use WinXP. Now, after switching, this is the error I'm getting:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, 
Version=1.0.66.0, Culturre-neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies.  
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

I haven't been able to find a solution for this, but here's what I tried so far:

1. Switch back to 4.5 - Didn't work
2. Add the reference again - Didn't work

Anyone know a solution?

Comment: Something like target problem, i.e. your build configuration may be switched to AnyCPU but only x86 available for `System.Data.SQLite`. Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048914/what-causes-system-badimageformatexception-when-constructing-system-data-sqlite

Comment: Switching back and forth between CPU configs doesn't fix it. Either way, it used to work before switching frameworks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Instead of linking to an image elsewhere, please include all relevant content inside your question (as I have edited it above).  Images can also be uploaded and embedded directly.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'll keep that in mind next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to fix this is to download an updated version of the SQLite library for your target framework from http://system.data.sqlite.org.

The older System.Data.SQLite assembly that you are using is a mixed code assembly that targets .NET 2.0. The default policy under .NET 4 is to not allow such assemblies to load, but you can explicitly allow it for a process by adding something like this into the MyApp.exe.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Note that the change can break other things though.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179028/mixed-mode-assembly-in-net-4) covers similar ground:

Comment: That's already been added to the config file, it's still not loading. I also have the latest version of the dll

Comment: The one that's in the question is the one I've been getting, yes

Comment: Well that error refers to the old version of SQLite - the 1.0.66 is not recent at all. Perhaps your project is picking up the reference from somewhere you don't expect?

Comment: Hm, that is unexpected yeah, I downloaded the latest version this morning. I'll check if that's the issue.